# Insta-like filters on Google Street view imagery

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Is it eligible to apply real-time insta-like filters on Google Street View imagery retrieved via the google street view API that will be published online as a part of a slideshow in a web app?

No Google street view Content will be cached on a third party server in the process.
Do you think this would be in alignment with google's terms?

Answer (score 0):

Streetview seems to be under the Google Maps umbrella as far as the api TOS goes. The [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) isn't that long, but your use case doesn't seem to be in direct violation. I would still be wary of something such as Section 8.3 (a):

> Content (including but not limited to map data, traffic, directions,
>   and places) is provided for planning purposes only. You may find that weather conditions, construction projects, closures, or other events may cause road conditions or directions to differ from the results depicted in the Content. You should exercise judgment in your use of the Content.

Although that seems more like a caveat emptor warning admonishing them of liability if their data is inaccurate and tells you to turn left off of a cliff. I insist that you should really read the [actual terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms). There are a lot of little things that they seem to be worried about in there and I would definitely recommend having an attorney help you navigate what's going on in there.

I'd hazard to say you'd be fine especially with no caching, but you should really consult with an attorney and [read the terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I had thoroughly examined google's TOS on google Maps API before asking. I'm especially concerned about 10.1.3 (a) and whether displaying google street view imagery with added effects (but without blurring or deleting) would be considered as a modification of the original Content. 

I guess seeking Legal advice might be the best way to go.